# Using escaped string with String.Format results in Format Exception

Tags: c#, string.format

I get a System.Format exception when trying this:

```
var jsonString = String.Format( @"{
    ""searchOptions"": {
        ""departurePosition"": { ""id"": {0} },
        ""arrivalPosition"": { ""id"": 376422 },
        ""travelModes"": [ ""Flight"", ""Train"", ""Bus"" ],
        ""departureDate"": ""2017-01-15"",
        ""passengers"": [
          {
            ""age"": 12,
            ""discountCards"": [ ]
          }
        ],
        ""userInfo"": {
          ""identifier"": ""0.jhvlf8amtgk"",
          ""domain"": "".com"",
          ""locale"": ""en"",
          ""currency"": ""EUR""
        },
        ""abTestParameters"": [ ]
    }
}", departurePosition);
```

I need this when sending a post request to a server.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Create a class which will represent the data and use `var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDataInstance)` to create a json string.

Comment: As @Fabio suggested, the best option to create a maintainable solution for your Json output would be to create classes an use a library like Newtonsoft to create a valid output. As an example, I created a small demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LlJ4LD)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because the use of `{` and `}`
To Escape the `{` and `}` use `{{` and `}}`

Answer (score 0):

OfirW already shared this,
[string.Format() giving “Input string is not in correct format”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951509/3615478)

If this is just one variable, regular string concatenation will work fine.

```
var jsonString =  
@"{ ""searchOptions"": {
        ""departurePosition"": { ""id"": " + departurePosition + @"},
        ""arrivalPosition"": { ""id"": 376422 },
        ""travelModes"": [ ""Flight"", ""Train"", ""Bus"" ],
        ""departureDate"": ""2017-01-15"",
        ""passengers"": [
          {
            ""age"": 12,
            ""discountCards"": [ ]
          }
        ],
        ""userInfo"": {
          ""identifier"": ""0.jhvlf8amtgk"",
          ""domain"": "".com"",
          ""locale"": ""en"",
          ""currency"": ""EUR""
        },
        ""abTestParameters"": [ ]
  }
}";
```