# C# StringBuilder AppendFormat throwing System.FormatException

Tags: c#, razor, stringbuilder

I have this method below which I've simplified to reproduce the problem, can anyone explain why the system format exception is thrown?

I have tried adding the @ to the beginning of the format string in-case it was a problem with escape characters but it didn't help.

```
private void doThing(StringBuilder builder, string inPrimaryKey) {
    // At this point the builder.ToString() results in "            <div  class="v-group width-100 shadowed OrderPanel"
    // and inPrimaryKey is "OrderId"

    // Throws System.FormatException with the detail "Input string was not in a correct format."
    builder.AppendFormat(@" @if (Model.{0} > 0) { <text>StateNonEditable</text> } else { <text>StateEditable</text> }", inPrimaryKey);
}
```

A bit of background, we're using this code to generate a cshtml page for use in a web app so the stringbuilder initially contains some html and then we are adding some C# MVC Razor within the format section.

Comment: remove @ from inner string and try

Comment: duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951479/string-format-giving-input-string-is-not-in-correct-format

Comment: @Patrick Hofman thanks, i did search for format exception errors but didnt come across those as i didnt know to search for the curly brace :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> can anyone explain why the system format exception is thrown?

Yes: your format string includes this:

```
{ <text>StateNonEditable</text> }
```

That's not a valid format item. You need to escape the braces that *aren't* meant to be part of a format item by doubling them:

```
builder.AppendFormat(
    " @if (Model.{0} > 0) {{ <text>StateNonEditable</text> }} else {{ <text>StateEditable</text> }}",
    inPrimaryKey);
```

Alternatively, just call `AppendFormat` once and then `Append` once:

```
builder.AppendFormat(" @if (Model.{0} > 0 ", inPrimaryKey)
       .Append("{ <text>StateNonEditable</text> } else { <text>StateEditable</text> }");
```

That's probably a more readable solution, to be honest.